# Are questions regarding the Android L developer preview on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Google released a developer preview of Android "L" Wednesday at their I/O conference. Is that developer preview on topic?

Comment: If the questions are from an end user perspective, perhaps ... a build for developers tends to preclude that.

Comment: So far we've accepted questions about ART, which has been a developer preview (and still is until L proper is released), so logically it seems we have to. But questioners need to expect "don't use the developer preview then" as an answer to some questions.

Answer (score 5):

I would say they *are* on-topic. However...

- The universe of people who could know the answer is rather small. There may not be anybody here who can answer your question.
- It is a preview, so a lot of things are going to change. A problem you ask about today may get fixed in the released version, or even in a later review build. Stack Exchange is about the "long tail". That is, for the people who come after who have the same problem the Asker did. A question (and its answers) for a problem that no one can ever have any more is of no use.
- And, of course, developer (programming) questions are off-topic regardless of OS version.

Comment: I've also heard, anecdotally, that this is _very much_ a developer preview and isn't nearly ready for end users.

Comment: That's very true there's a lot of quilt work in there still, bits of Kitkat stitched to the new stuff. I'd imagine a lot of answers now will be "It's a bug" with a very early build.